# Having issues with INNER JOIN in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to select rows from 2 tables with only one SQL statement. Could anybody help me figure out how to make this code work?

This is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT *. 
FROM PersonalTable
INNER JOIN ON Employees.PersonalID = PersonalTable.PersonalID 
WHERE PersonalID = " + PersonalID.ToString()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to list the Employees table as the target of your join:

```
SELECT * FROM PersonalTable 
INNER JOIN Employees 
ON Employees.PersonalID = PersonalTable.PersonalID 
WHERE Employees.PersonalID= etc
```

Comment: Thank you so much , although there seems to be a new exception thrown at me, which is Column name 'PersonalID' is ambiguous.
I tried specifying the PersonalID and it did not seem to help, do you have any suggestion on how I could solve this ?

Comment: Just add the table modifier to PersonalID in the where clause. PersonalTable.PersonalID